# Актуальная книга по Node js

Tags: javascript, node.js, книги

Хочу изучить Node.js, интересует именно печатная книга, и на русском.
Посоветуйте пожалуйста самую лучшую и актуальную на сегодняшнее время

Хотел приобрести `Node.js в действии (2е издание)`, но нигде нет в наличии.
И мне сказали что у неё не очень хорошие отзывы... не знаю так ли это

Comment: а где вообще можно подробно разобраться в ноде? Кроме документации, которая служит скорее как описание имеющихся функций. Что-нибудь типо книги-документации у rust?

Comment: Скорее всего, ответы на этот вопрос будут основаны на мнениях, а не на фактах и цитатах. Необходимо переформулировать его так, чтобы на него можно было дать объективный ответ.

Answer (score 1):

Действительно как ответить на вопрос если учитывать, что печатное издание выходит в течении нескольких месяцев - это я преуменьшил, а обновление node.js каждые 2 недели. Думаю всё что вы найдете в печатном виде будет не много либо сыро, либо не совсем актуальным.

Обновлено с учетом комментария.
Раз вы ищите бумажную книгу нужно пробежаться по популярным издательствам.

[Питер](https://www.piter.com/collection/all?q=node)

[DMK Press](https://dmkpress.com/search/product/?search_string=node)

.....

их изданиям.

Comment: В данном случае под словом 'актуальная' я имел ввиду 'не устаревшая'.
Новые функции можно доучить, а вот переучиваться заново не хотелось бы.

Comment: @HaZcker https://webbooks.com.ua/books-main/node-js-v-dejstvii-2018-pdf-yang-a-mek-b-kantelon-m/ ссылка на книгу которую вы искали. напишите потом я удалю качайте с Скачать с CLOUD Webbooks

Comment: Дело в том, что электронная версия не подходит, я это указал в вопросе. Объясню почему. Не подходит потому что я хочу купить бумажную версию книги, и читать в "свободное от монитора" время. То есть изучать Node когда глаза отдыхают от экрана монитора/телефона/etc. Поэтому меня интересует именно книга, а не курсы, статьи, и тд

Comment: Эта та книга которую вы искали. Просто распечатайте её так как продаже книги нет

Comment: Конкурс окончен. что решили?